# Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0

Tags: node.js

guys. I have a than error in my NodeJS rest API, and can't resolve this.

My idea is make a github login, this app working like this.

Href to github url returning a temporal code in callback.

Latter, send this temporal code to my REST API and with rest api make a fetch request to other endpoint of the github api, and this endpoint should return `access_token=12345` (this access token is a example), for latter send this token to frontend, and convert the token in a JWT token and also send to frontend for latter storage in a localStorage to use it.

My code in NodeJS

```js
router.post("/users/github/:code",function(req,res){
    fetch('https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token/', {
        method: 'GET',
        client_id: 'xxxx',
        client_secret: 'xxxx',
        code: req.params.code,
        accept: 'json',
    })
   .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
    }).then(function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    });
 
});
```

PD: I use `node-fetch` module for this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

Comment: Shouldn't it be `accept: 'application/json'`? Also, you are shadowing `res` in your promise handler. Not that it won't work, just be careful that you are using the variable you intend to use when you shadow like that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution

```js
router.post("/users/github/:code",function(req,res){
    fetch('https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        client_id: 'xxxx',
        client_secret: 'xxxx',
        code: req.params.code
    })
}).then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
}).then(function(body) {
    res.json(body);
    }); 
});
```